# Change SMTP port - Snow Leopard Server

Tags: email, postfix, smtp, osx-snow-leopard

I am using Snow Leopard Server's mail service to relay mail through my ISP's mail relay over port 25. However, they requested that I start using port 587. How can I change the port used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When inserting the name of the host through which to relay outbound mail, add brackets around the name, then add a colon followed by the port number.

`smtp.example.com` becomes `[smtp.example.com]:587`

[image]